# Change enviornment to JDK in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse Luna (Java EE IDE). I need to add jdk because my project is been converted to maven. Whenever , I install maven console gives an error

> No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
>   on a JRE rather than a JDK?

So i used Preference>installed jre's. However , when i am trying to change JRE to JDK by using Search button in Installed jre's. It shows me only JRE not JDK. Although , i am providing JDK path.

In short , I need to change my environment to JDK.

Thanks. Please help me out

Comment: Did you try with "ADD" button above search? you should add the JDK to your instaled JREs and then checkbox that one to be used by eclipse. If it still not works, can you provide the path pls to your JDK so we know what you are actually doing?

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project SpringIntegrationStruts: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? Thats the error I am getting

Answer (score 2):

In the preferences screen, remove the JRE listed there.
Add > Standard VM + Next > Directory + navigate to the jre directory inside jdk folder and Finish

If done right then JRE Home should look like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre", NOT "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8"

Next, make sure you have the new JRE System Library listed under the Libraries tab in Java build path and in the Java Compiler (right click on project > properties) you define enable project specifics and set Compiler compliance level to the version you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just open: Window-> Preferences ->Installed JREs and press SEARCH. Chose a folder and eclips find all avaliable jre and sdk.